# Docker compose deployment downtime vs capistrano?

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, capistrano

I know that it is rolling updates in swarm mode for zero downtime deployment.

But for simple projects,I wonder if using docker-compose in production and using deployment from docs:

```
$ docker-compose build web
$ docker-compose up --no-deps -d web
```

What is going to be downtime comparing to changing symbolic with Capistrano script?

Answer (score 2):

This entirely depends on what infrastructure you're running, how heavy the containers are, how long your application takes to startup, and other factors. Really all you can do is test both and collect some metrics on them.

If this is a small side project or service that is used sparingly in a business then I wouldn't worry too much about the spin up time, starting containers themselves can often be very fast. The delay you're going to need to think about is how long it takes your application to actually start once the container is alive. If it takes 2 minutes to start the service outside of a container, it's going to be the same inside the container.

Sadly you'ure going to need to test this yourself to get a definitive answer.